# How I bring back property thingy in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I accidently closed the property thing in VS2008, you know the one where when you're using Winforms you can edit like a controls text, font, dock, anchor, etc, etc.

How I get it back can't find!

To clarify it's the side panel thingy where you can edit control properties... usually goes side by side with the Toolbox, like you can't develop a Winform application wtihout this panel and I can't figure how to open it omg QQ!

Comment: It's for this reason why I think all GUI should have a "Thingy" menu that lists all the random things that can be displayed/hidden. Some have "Window" and "View", but they don't put all the "thingies" I would expect in that menu.

Comment: In 2008, the property window is listed in the "View thingy". As are most other dialogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select a control on the forms designer and press <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: No I mean, the little dock panel toolbar thingy on the side where its like a GUI interface to change properties.

Comment: Yeah, that's what F4 does.  Maybe you have a non-standard keyboard layout?  Try the View/Properties Window menu or right-click/properties.

Comment: Right click properties worked.  F4 just brought me to the partial class with the generated code.